# VMwareのホストとCUIのみのゲスト間のクリップボード共有

Tags: linux, vim, emacs, debian, vmware

VMware Player にCUIのみのdebainをインストールして使っているのですが、ホスト(windows)でコピーしたものをゲストOS(debian)のemacsやvimに貼り付けられるようにしたいのですがどうやったらできるのでしょうか？

VMware toolはインストールしましたが変わらなかったです。
またemacsとvimは一回閉じるとクリップボードの中身が消えてしまいます。
CUIのみではそもそもクリップボード共有はできないんでしょうか？

Comment: VimやEmacs等でコピーしたテキストはクリップボードではなく、エディタ内での利用に限定した「バッファ」と呼ばれるメモリ領域に保存されています。Emacsはあまり詳しくないですが少なくともVimに関しては、他のアプリとデータをやり取りするにはVimがクリップボード連携を有効にした状態でコンパイルされたものを利用したり、設定ファイルへオプションの記述が必要だったりします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unix 系の OS では通常クリップボード機能は X が提供します。CUI のみの場合は、クリップボードと言う概念は OS にはないはずです。
lemonade と言うソフトウェアを使うと、そういった環境でも外部とクリップボードのやりとりをすることができます。
リンク先を参考にしてみてください。

lemonade 配布元
https://github.com/pocke/lemonade

作者による紹介記事
http://pocke.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/07/04/235118
http://pocke.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/08/23/221543

手前味噌ですが、私による紹介記事
https://thinca.hatenablog.com/entry/introduce-lemonade

Answer (score 4):

WindowsからTeraTermなどのエミュレータでゲストに接続する方法もあると思います。