# VMware player でWindowsでコピーしたテキストを仮想のcui linux でペーストしたい。

Tags: linux, vmware

タイトル通りのことをしようとすると以下の警告が出るのですがどうすればいいのでしょうか？
CD-ROMをゲスト内部から取り出すという処理はどうすればできるのでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: この辺の記事が類似の話題を扱っているようです。[VMWare Playerでコピー&ペースト(コピペ)ができないときの原因と対処方法 | 仮想マシンソフト](https://aresei-note.com/1089), [vmwareのcuiでホストとゲスト間のクリップボード共有するには](https://teratail.com/questions/110186)

Comment: 重複候補: [VMwareのホストとCUIのみのゲスト間のクリップボード共有](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/42953)